# Maximum likelihood estimation in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space of a ball

Tags: statistics, euclidean-geometry, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I have a set of points in $d$-dimension Euclidean space drawn from a ball centered at point $c$ and with radius $r$ which are unknown. I want help in formulating the maximum likelihood estimator of $r$ and $c$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you hazard a *guess* at the solution?  Perhaps the center is the mean of the data and the radius is the distance to the farthest point from that center??

Comment: I just want to formulate it for now. Because there arnt other any other constraints

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : Your guess wrong in this case. Consider the points $(-10,0),\, (0,1),\, (10,0).$ The MLE is $c=(0,0),\, r=10. \qquad$

Comment: I guess we just want the smallest sphere that contains the points.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : Correct. Remember the well known answer in the $1$-dimensional case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're uniformly distributed in the ball, then the value of the probability density at every point in the ball is equal to the reciprocal of the volume of the ball. The values of $c$ and $r$ that maximize that density, subject to the constraint that all of the observed points lie within the ball, are the values of $c$ and $r$ that give you the smallest possible ball containing the observed points.

That reduces the problem to one of geometry. Possibly more that is of interest could be said about the geometry problem.

Comment: Just formulating without any constraints might help

Comment: @m2rik : How? MLEs are done with data. The data are the only constraint in this problem.

Comment: I mean I only want to formulate the optimisation problem and not actually optimise it because I dont have any data

Comment: @m2rik : You began by saying you have a set of points in $d$-dimensional space. That set of points is the data.

Comment: Alright. Ill try to formulate the question better.

Comment: Here's the formal algorithm for @MichaelHardy's solution:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem

Comment: The optimization problem is to minimize $r^2$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^d (x_i^j-c_i)^2 \le r^2$ for all points $j$, where $r$ and $c_i$ are the decision variables and $x_i^j$ is the $i$th coordinate of point $j$.

Comment: @RobPratt:  Umm... why can't your inequality be broken by adding as many points as necessary, thereby making the left-hand-side arbitrarily large?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Not sure what you mean.  The finite set of points are the input data to the problem.

Comment: OK.  Set the number of points to $10^9$, all within some constrained volume.  Won't the left-hand-side of your equation become extremely large and hence larger than $r^2$?

Comment: In the optimization problem, $r$ is a decision variable, so it will grow as large as needed to satisfy the constraints.  Also, there is a separate constraint for each point $j$, and the sum is over the dimensions $i$.